# Records Center Template allows Sandbox solutions in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sandbox-solution, records-center

Can some one please tell, can we activate Sandboxed solutions on a Record Centre template site?
When i upload a solution to gallery, i see the activate button is greyed out. I have checked the sandboxed service is activated on Manage services in farm.
Also i have activated the Document Parsing feature from Powershell and it shows True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reupload the solution and it should do the trick